# openssl: reducing memory usage

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, openssl

Good day. We have a server written on C++ that accept many SSL/TLS connections; we are using boost::asio (so backend is **openssl**) to establish SSL.

At the mement server is using about 160-200kbytes of memory per connection and we want to reduce this usage. boost::asio is using SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS flag by default, so basic optimisation is already done.. Playing with `ctx->freelist_max_len` seems changes nothing.

How this can be done? Maybe we there is a additional "secret setting"? Probably we can safely disable some encryption algorithms to reduce memory consuption?

Comment: have you looked at where the memory is being allocated? It could be anything, from what you've given. E.g. thread overhead?

Comment: @sehe according to **massif** at least 50% of this memory is allocated by `CRYPTO_malloc`, so idle connections is taking many memory and im trying to optimise this part somehow. Its important part since at each timepoint 99% of clients are idling.

Comment: Are you sure it's per connection? It should be per SSL session, if OpenSSL is working correctly. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @EJP how to check how many session i have? A client can make few connections to server at a time, so probably it can reuse sessions..

Comment: Have you enabled TLS session reuse with `SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context()`?

Comment: @Tiran no. I know this can speedup the handshake, but how about memory load?

Comment: It lowers memory load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I looked at the same thing, I profiled my application using massif when 1000 clients were connected.

- Test 1: Without using SSL. Peak memory usage hit 2.871MB.
- Test 2: With SSL, default settings. Peak memory of 617.3MB.
- Test 3: With SSL compression disabled. Peak memory 41.93MB.
- Test 4: Modified test 3 with SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS enabled as well. Peak memory of 11.49MB.

That gets down to 11.5kB per connection, although this will be different in your application of course.

You're already using SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS but you could consider disabling compression as well. Disabling compression can be achieved with the below. It requires openssl >= 1.0.

`SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | <other options>);`

or

`SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | <other options>);`

Comment: How can I check if the option and the mode has been set correctly on the sever ? 
I tried using s_client where I could see if the compression is enabled or not but I did not find a way to check if the mode SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS.