# reducing memory usage per connection with boost::asio ssl server

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I am working on ssl server using boost::asio. I am looking to reduce memory usage per one ssl connection as much as possible.

My code is mostly derived from 
[boost::asio::ssl example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp) server example. That means I am storing sessions as a Session class object, that has sslContext attribute, registered read_handler, etc. (pretty much as it is in the example)

All the optimalization that I could find is enabling `SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS` and `SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION`. And right now I am at around 55kB per connection.

However according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954918/openssl-reducing-memory-usage), you can reduce memory usage down to 11kB.

Is there anything else I can do to reduce this usage?

OS: Ubuntu 11.04 and boost version: 1_55

Answer (score 1):

Its important question for me too, so I studied a bit about it.

Currently asio::ssl engine implementation has at least 34kB memory overhead. You can see it in the source code [stream_core.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/asio/ssl/detail/stream_core.hpp), `max_tls_record_size`. **valgind massif** tool confirms this. But, I did not managed to find how to avoid this since those buffers is used deeply in the **io_op**.